# How do I load a Class Library DLL at runtime and run a class function using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, dll, runtime, .net-assembly

Say I've a class like this inside a class library project called SomeClass-

```
Public Class SomeClass
  Public Function DoIt() as String
    Return "Do What?"
  End Function
End Class
```

I get a `SomeClass.dll` which I want to load at runtime from another Windows Forms Application, and then have it call the `DoIt()` function and show it's value in a messagebox or something. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to make `DoIt` shared, since it does not require class state:

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Public Shared Function DoIt() as String
        Return "Do What?"
    End Function
End Class
```

Then calling it is easy:

```
' Loads SomeClass.dll
Dim asm = Assembly.Load("SomeClass")  

' Replace the first SomeClass with the base namespace of your SomeClass assembly
Dim type = asm.GetType("SomeClass.SomeClass")

Dim returnValue = DirectCast(type.InvokeMember("DoIt", _
                                               BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static, _
                                               Nothing, Nothing, {}),
                             String)
```

If you cannot make the method shared, you can create an instance of your class with [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx) and pass it as a parameter to [Type.InvokeMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx).

<sub>All my code examples assume Option Strict On and Option Infer On.</sub>