# Explicit (runtime) DLL linking with Visual Basic 2013 Fails

Tags: vb.net, dll, runtime

I wrote a dll in Visual Basic on Visual Studio 2013 (what it does is irrelevant now):

```
Namespace TextFiles

    Public Class ConfigTextFiles
        'Library of functions to handle configuration text files holding pairs of parm-name, param-value.
        'Param-name and Param-value are separated by the Delimiter property, or "=" if not set.

        Shared strDelimiter As String
        Shared intRowsCount As Integer


        Public Shared Function getParamValue(ByVal strFileLocation As String, ByVal strFileName As String, ByVal strParamName As String) As String
            'Return the value of a specific parameter within the text file
            'Return an empty string if param-name is not found
            'Return vbNullChar if file was not found

            Dim TextLine() As String
            Dim strFullFileName As String

            If Right(strFileLocation, 1) = "\" Then
                strFullFileName = strFileLocation & strFileName
            Else
                strFullFileName = strFileLocation & "\" & strFileName
            End If

            getParamValue = ""
            If System.IO.File.Exists(strFullFileName) = True Then
                If (IsNothing(strDelimiter)) Then strDelimiter = "="
                Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(strFullFileName)

                Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                    TextLine = Split(objReader.ReadLine(), strDelimiter)
                    If (Trim(strParamName) = Trim(TextLine(0))) Then
                        getParamValue = Trim(TextLine(1))
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
                objReader = Nothing
            Else
                MsgBox("File Does Not Exist: " & strFullFileName, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "File Open Error")
                getParamValue = vbNullChar

            End If
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

This DLL is called: SisConfigTextFiles.dll and is stored in the folder of the executing (calling) (exe) file.

I want to explicitly link to it at runtime, from another Visual Basic application:

```
Public Class Initializing
    Public Const CONFIG_FILE_NAME As String = "AppConfig.ini" 

    Public Shared Function getConfigParam(ParamName As String) As String
        'Load external dll
        Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.Load("SisConfigTextFiles")
        Dim type As Type = asm.GetType("TextFiles.ConfigTextFiles")

        ' Create an instance of a Type by calling Activator.CreateInstance
        Dim dynamicObject As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(type)

        Dim appPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath

        getConfigParam = ""
        Dim returnValue = DirectCast(type.InvokeMember("getParamValue", _
                                               BindingFlags.InvokeMethod Or BindingFlags.Static, _
                                               Nothing, dynamicObject, {appPath, CONFIG_FILE_NAME, ParamName}), String)
        getConfigParam = returnValue
    End Function

End Class
```

However, I keep getting this runtime error:

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type

Why is "type" Null? How can I straighten this out?

Thanks!

Comment: There is [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), probably available in VB as it is windows core functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15358788/2319909

Comment: Thanks Sam. Yes, it looks like a duplicate. However, I could not get it to work. I'm now updating this question to be more specific.

Comment: @Sam, can you please un-mark this question as having been answered, this is no longer the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there but this line isnt valid:

```
asm.GetType("TextFiles.ConfigTextFiles")
```

It should be

```
asm.GetType("SisConfigTextFiles.TextFiles.ConfigTextFiles")
```

You can see the available types in the `Assembly.ExportedTypes` property.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. This gives me the following error: System.MissingMethodException: Method 'SisConfigTextFiles.TextFiles.ConfigTextFiles.getParamValue' not found.
I could not get "ExportedTypes" to work. Can you please show how to use in this context?

Comment: No problem.  Sorry for not full testing the code! This error is due to the binding flags on the InvokeMember call.  Add 'BindingFlags.Public'.

Comment: If you're all sorted please can you mark the answer as correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following Sam's advice, here's the fully working code that invokes a method in a DLL with late (run-time) binding:

```
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class Initializing
    Public Const CONFIG_FILE_NAME As String = "AppConfig.ini"

    Public Shared Sub Config_Init()

    End Sub


    Public Shared Function getConfigParam(ParamName As String) As String
        'Load external dll
        Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.Load("SisConfigTextFiles")
        Dim type As Type = asm.GetType("SisConfigTextFiles.TextFiles.ConfigTextFiles")


        ' Create an instance of a Type by calling Activator.CreateInstance
        Dim dynamicObject As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(type)

        Dim appPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath

        getConfigParam = ""
        'Invoking a function "setParamValue" in the dll
        Dim returnValue = DirectCast(type.InvokeMember("getParamValue", _
                                               BindingFlags.InvokeMethod Or BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.Public, _
                                               Nothing, dynamicObject, {appPath, CONFIG_FILE_NAME, ParamName}), String)
        getConfigParam = returnValue
    End Function

End Class
```